# twitter integration using javascript mvc5

Tags: javascript

I used below code to get request token and try to open twitter login page on button click in MVC5

But it will give sucess but in "data" field i am not able to get request token.

Please help me out how i can resolve my issue

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var time = currentTime.getTime();
var code = getNonce();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        _url: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
    },
    dataType: "text",
    headers: {  
        "oauth_nonce": code,
        "oauth_callback": "http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F",
        "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA1",
        "oauth_timestamp": time,
        "oauth_consumer_key": "tCofU3Vil5BRFwQT7JdmpNKrP",
        "oauth_signature": "oR9%2BzVEd4AlvpYdNwP6onuVDBFM%3D",
        "oauth_version": "1.0"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        alert("Success!");
        window.open('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=b6bb1a2f8ff545128f8c1c0aa216be8c')
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Something went wrong...");
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```